# Angular4 / Child element not firing parent (click) event

Tags: angular, typescript, events, event-bubbling

I have a dropdown function which should be called with a click on this div

```
<div (click)="toggleDropdown($event)" data-id="userDropdown">
 Username <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
```

But the click event is  not triggered when I click on the `<i>` element

```
toggleDropdown($event) {
    const id = $event.target;
    document.querySelector('[data-drop=' + id.getAttribute('data-id') + ']').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Anyway i can make it that the child click event to trigger the parent one?

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ztk6P2kk9J50fXS3vZQE?p=preview)

Comment: Show components code. Is this `html` and a `toggleDropdown` function are part of the same component?

Comment: Yes, They are both in the same component. Sorry that i wasnt clear enough

Comment: that's weird, create a plunker

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ztk6P2kk9J50fXS3vZQE?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$event.currentTarget` instead of `$event.target`

This way you will get the element to which the event handler has been attached.

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/PbR821SZudL6FrhM1abX?p=preview)**

Read more

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget